# QML highest number (float/integer) possible

Tags: qt, math, numbers, qml

In JavaScript the highest integer possible is defined via

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.
```

and also in C++ can be obtained with the std:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Is there such a constant in QML for ints or doubles?

Comment: [int](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-int.html) QML basic type

Comment: So we must just use the value 2000000000? No constant available? Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html) but yeah, at the moment the (absolutely not correct but at least related) only choice is `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: 2000000000 sounds very strange and illogical. That value doesn't correspond to any particular binary representation.

Comment: They mean the usual 32bit signed int range -2^31=-2147483648 to 2^31-1=2147483647 which is around -2e9 to 2e9.

Comment: Still, this is not a value that can and should be approximated. I personally wished they implemented proper integer support in QML. I had an application where I needed to use 64bit integers that kept getting bugged, until I realized in JS integers go only to like 2^53 IIRC. The default QML `int` works fine because it is well within that range, but its own range is rather limited.

Answer (score 4):

As originally suspected, the `2000000000` number listed in the documentation is incorrect. Also, IMO this is an important value that shouldn't really be subject to such careless approximations. "Around" should only be used when the actual value is unknown for certain or not crucial.

A simple test verifies that the largest possible value for an `int` property in QML is `2147483647`, or as expected `2^31 - 1`.

Note that this is different from `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is a JS thing, and that value is `2^53 - 1` - substantially higher than what `int` will give you. `Number` is a 64 bit real data type, and it supports integers by using the 53 fraction bits of the number, the 11 exponent bits are left unused.

Edit: In 5.15 and possibly earlier, it is possible to use the full range of an unsigned 32 bit int, doubling the effective range over qml's `int` type, but you have to use `var` as the property type, it may even be possible to use uint64 with values within the `^53` range.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use [IntValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-intvalidator.html). By default, top and bottom property contains the maximum and minimum Qt int value.

```
readonly property IntValdiator intValdiator: IntValidator {}
readonly property int MAX_VALUE: intValidator.top
readonly property int MIN_VALUE: intValidator.bottom
```

Answer (score 1):

The constants you need are `-Infinity` and `Infinity`, or `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`and `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`