# How to control fromat for big numbers in QML like (-715827883)

Tags: javascript, qml

I have a variable like val=1
I have applied certain condition.
When the condition is true then val is multiplied by 3.
like 3, 9, 27, 81, 243..........
but after a long loop it shows like -715827883 value.
Why?

I want my result like,when i start to execute my loop reversely then val/3 is executed and at the end it will give 1.
But now it's giving 0.

Please suggest.

Comment: Hi there! Your problem was most likely caused due to integers being limited to a certain number of bits, but this is only a guess. (We don't know what your code looks like.) Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce it. Thanks :-)

Comment: var val=1

if(tile.enabled==true)

val=val*3

else if(tile.enabled==false)

val=val/3

Comment: This is a task which i have been assigned. So it will be difficult to sent whole project because linking is in different files. So I am sending dummy syntax which i want same.
@TrebuchetMS

Comment: Ok, you've included some js there (although please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54194560/edit) your question to contain any code). And... where are you calling this js? In a slot? A function? Component.onCompleted? We don't need your entire project, just a minimal example. Thanks again.

Comment: With the js code you've provided, assuming that it's all contained in one block... your code doesn't demonstrate your issue since `var val = 1` will be disposed when the scope is exited (be it function or slot).

Comment: Related: [Qml Highest Number/Float Integer Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378583/qml-highest-number-float-integer-possible)